# How to share a static method amongst several class

Tags: c#, static, polymorphism

I'd like to start with something like this:

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }
class C { ... }
```

Where A, B and C have a static method MyName.

Then I could do:

```
Console.WriteLine(A.MyName());
Console.WriteLine(B.MyName());
Console.WriteLine(C.MyName());
```

Then after I should be able to do something like this.

```
foreach(var type in new[] { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C)) {
    ??? Console.WriteLine(t.MyName());
}
```

How could I do that?

I'd also like to be able to do the following (but that may be impossible):

```
??? x = new A();
Console.WriteLine(x.MyName());
x = new B();
Console.WriteLine(x.MyName());
```

Comment: static method? Where have you mentioned method here?

Comment: A base class? I'm also confused by the last example. What is `t` - did you meant `type`? - and why do you think MyName will be on the `System.Type` type?

Comment: @wudzik, in my example I used a static property. I get I could add parenthesis to make it look like a method.

Comment: @vcjones, I don't think it will, that's where I'm looking for answer thus the three question marks "???".

Comment: There's also no direct sign of polymorphism present like your tagging implies.

Comment: @bump, if there's a method to get a list of types while making the engine knows those have a MyName() method, then it's just what I wish for. And it's polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is associate Metadata with a type, which can be queried if you know the type.  The standard practice for doing this is to use [Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56.aspx).  You can query these attributes in a type-safe way and extract the associated information for each attribute. They are quite flexible in how you specify their inheritance and whether you can apply more than one of the same attribute type.  They can also be applied to other things besides classes, like properties or fields, which can be handy.

---

Here's a simple demo program (the null check isn't strictly necessary here, but just demonstrating how you check whether an attribute actually exists.)  Note that the extension method that provides a generic GetCustomAttribute was only added in .NET 4.5.  Prior versions will require you to use a non-generic version and cast it to the appropriate attribute type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var types = new[] {typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C)};
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<NameAttribute>();
            if (attribute != null)
                Console.WriteLine(attribute.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public sealed class NameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public NameAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    [Name("A Name")]
    public class A
    {
    }

    [Name("B Name")]
    public class B
    {
    }

    [Name("C Name")]
    public class C
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how can I retrieve those attributes' values in a loop (like the foreach loop in my example)?

Comment: GetCustomAttribute didn't show up (Intelisense) when I was on 4.5 so I tried 4.5.1 and it now shows up. Could it actually be a 4.5.1 feature? Anyway, it return a enumerable so the check uses Any() and the output using First().

Comment: if you could just check the points I mentioned before, I could mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: GetCustomAttribute should be supported in 4.5, but you need to add `using System.Reflection`.  I neglected to include that above; I honestly lose track of namespaces as I'm so used to Resharper adding them for me whenever I need by pressing Alt-Enter.  This particular extension method does not return an enumerable, but rather a single instance.  In any case, with the correct namespaces, the above code sample compiles and runs properly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to share some static member between classes you need to inherit from base class which will contain static member:

```
public class Base
{
    public static string MyName() { return "Bob"; }
}

public class A : Base
{        
}

public class B : Base
{
}
```

You can't do what you are trying in your foreach loop, because variable `t` has type `Type` and `Type` do not have any `MyName` properties. You should use reflection to get `MyName` value:

```
Console.WriteLine(A.MyName()); // Bob
Console.WriteLine(B.MyName()); // Bob

foreach(var type in new[] { typeof(A), typeof(B) })
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
    var method = type.GetMethod("MyName", flags);
    Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null, null));
}
```

This code prints `Bob` for both types.

Comment: A and B are going to share they same static backing field this way.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid relying on reflection ?

Comment: @Serge no, you can't avoid it. Thus you have only type metadata (variable of `Type` type) then reflection is the only way to call static method.

Comment: Any guideline how to avoid risk of breaking code if I ever change "MyName" to something else (like "ShortName")?

Comment: @Serge use instance methods and polymorphism. Why you want method to be static?

Comment: How else could I get information on my class? Creating instances just to retrieve a class data feels ugly.

Comment: @Serge creating `Type` instances doesn't looks better to me. Also I completely do not understand why you are iterating over types here. If they share same static member, result will be same for each type. You can simply call `Base.MyName()`

Comment: @lazy MyName() would return different name for each class. My real goal is to iterate to every class of the current assembly that match a filtering and display a user friendly name for each class (Type.Name wouldn't be user friendly enough).

Comment: @Serge then do not use static members. Use attributes to add metadata to your types